# grunt load dynamic JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, gruntjs, npm

Is it possible to load a JSON file from a dynamic source? I want to do some localisation

```
grunt.file.readJSON('src/locales/<%= grunt.task.current.args[0] %>/i18n.json');
```

A fuller example of the Gruntfile looks like:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  var i18n = {
    locales: ['en', 'fr', 'de', 'es'],
    default: 'en',
    replacements: function(locale){
      var content = grunt.file.readJSON('src/locales/<%= grunt.task.current.args[0] %>/i18n.json');
      var arr = [];
      for(i in content){
        var replacement = {
          from: i,
          to: content[i].value
        };
      arr.push(replacement);
     }

    return arr;
  }
};
// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
  replace: {
  build: {
    src: ['local/en/**/*.html'],             // source files array (supports minimatch)
    dest: 'local/<%= grunt.task.current.args[0] %>/',             // destination directory or file
    replacements: i18n.replacements('<%= grunt.task.current.args[0] %>')
  }
},
```

While registering the task looks like:

```
grunt.registerTask('localise', function(){
  var tasks = [];
  for(i in i18n.locales){
    if(i18n.locales[i] !== i18n.default){

      tasks.push('replace:build:' + i18n.locales[i]);
    }
  }
  grunt.task.run(tasks);
});
```

Everything works as I'd hoped except loading the JSON to actually do the replacements.

I've also tried:

```
grunt.file.readJSON('src/locales/'+locale+'/i18n.json');
```

which didn't work either, leaving me a little stumped.

Anyone able to help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
'src/locales/' + grunt.task.current.args[0] + '/i18n.json'
```

Comment: That gives `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`. I think it's down to when things are called, the init is happening before the tasks are being run.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it working after much trial and error:

I updated the function returning the data to:

```
var i18n = {
  locales: ['en', 'fr', 'de', 'es'],
  default: 'en',
  replacements: function(locale){

    var content = grunt.file.readJSON('src/locales/'+ locale +'/i18n.json');
    var arr = [{from: "/" + locale, to: "/en"}, {from: "Test", to: locale}];

    for(i in content){
      var replacement = {
        from: i,
        to: content[i].value
      };

      arr.push(replacement);
    }
    console.log(arr);
    return arr;
  }
};
```

Then set an empty array in the default task:

```
replace: {
  build: {
    src: ['local/en/**/*.html'],             // source files array (supports minimatch)
    dest: 'local/<%= grunt.task.current.args[0] %>/',             // destination directory or file
    replacements: []
  }
},
```

Which is updated using it's own task

```
grunt.registerTask('updateConf', function(locale){

    var content = i18n.replacements(locale);

    grunt.config('replace.build.replacements', content);

});
```

That is run just before the replace task:

```
grunt.registerTask('localise', function(){
  var tasks = [];
  for(i in i18n.locales){
    if(i18n.locales[i] !== i18n.default){
      tasks.push('updateConf:' + i18n.locales[i]);
      tasks.push('replace:build:' + i18n.locales[i]);
    }
  }   

  grunt.task.run(tasks);
});
```

Giving the right output. Probably not the most elegant of solutions but it works!